# How to group data with similar keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this data from CSV:

```
Group   Profession  Status          Count
6       Fisherman   Offer Accepted  1
6       Fisherman   All             1
7       Fisherman   Offer Accepted  1
7       Fisherman   All             1
8       Banker      Onboard         2
8       Banker      All             2
8       Cook        Onboard         4
8       Cook        All             4
8       Developer   Onboard         2
8       Developer   All             2
9       Banker      Onboard         2
9       Banker      Offer Accepted  1
9       Banker      All             3
```

Which I need to return as a JSON array:

```
"Fisherman" : {
    6 : {
        "Offer Accepted" : 1,
        "All" : 1
    },
    7 : {
        "Offer Accepted" : 1,
        "All" : 1
    }
},
"Banker" : {
    8 : {
        "Onboard" : 2,
        "All" : 2
    },
    9 : {
        "Onboard" : 2,
        "Offer Accepted" : 1,
        "All" : 3
    }
},
....so on
```

So far, what I did was I got all the unique Profession and Group.

Then I looped through all the data and compared if there's a match for Profession AND Group.

```
for(var d in data) {
    var json = [];
    for(var p in profession) {
        for(var g in group) {
            if(data[d]["Profession"] == profession[p] && data[d]["Group"] == group[g]) {
                json.push({data[d]["Status"] : data[d]["Count"]});
                // put 'json' variable in JSON array with key group? 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a match, I created an array wherein I pushed the Status and Count.

But I really don't know how to proceed from there.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please add the data as well.

Comment: `json.push({data[d]["Status"] : data[d]["Count"]})`  is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose data is an array with objects like,

```
{ Group: 6, Profession: 'Fisherman', Status: 'Offer Accepted', Count: 1 }
```

then you could use the following

```
var order = ['Profession', 'Group', 'Status'],
    object = {};

data.forEach(function (d) {
    order.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[d[a]] = r[d[a]] || {};
        return r[d[a]];
    }, object).Count = d.Count;
});
```

> How it works:
>
> `d` is an object with the structure like above. `oder` is an array with keys in the wanted order for the result `object`. (I renamed `json` to `object`, because [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is a string with a special formatting and not an object, like here necessary.)
>
> For an assignment of count, it is necessary to know the path to the property. This is granted with iterating over the `order` for the keys of the actual object `d`.

```
r[d[a]] = r[d[a]] || {};
```

This `d[a]` is taken for a check if the property exits and if not to assign an empty object.

At the end of the callback, the reference to the last object `r[d[a]]` is returned.

At last, a new property `Count` is assinged with the value of `d.Count`

> ```
> object                       a          d[a]           return value
> ---------------------------- ---------- -------------- ------------
> {}                           Profession Fisherman      {}
>                 /--------------------------------------/            (same reference)
> { "Fisherman": {} }          Group      6              {}
>                        /-------------------------------/            (same reference)
> { "Fisherman": { "6": {} } } Status     Offer Accepted {}
> ```
>
> object after first loop of data
>
> ```
> {
>     "Fisherman": {
>         "6": {
>             "Offer Accepted": {
>                 "Count": 1
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Roundup: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) returns something, which is highly controllable.

Comment: This did it. This is the first time I'll use `reduce`. Can you explain further your code? Especially this part `return r[d[a]]; }, json).Count = d.Count;` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = new Array();
for(var d in data){
    if(result[d.profession] == 'undefined'){
        result[d.profession] = new Array();
    }
    if(result[d.profession][d.group] == 'undefined'){
        result[d.profession][d.group] = new Array();
    }
    result[d.profession][d.group][d.status] = d.count;
}

result = JSON.stringify(result);//convert array to json
console.log(result);
```

I didn't test it and I supposed your JSON data are in data variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easy with reduce:

```
const result = data.reduce((result, row) => {
    ensureKeyExists(result, row.Profession);
  ensureKeyExists(result[row.Profession], row.Group);

  result[row.Profession][row.Group][row.Status] = row.Count;

  return result;
}, {});

function ensureKeyExists(object, key, defaultVal = {}) {
    if (!object[key]) {
    object[key] = defaultVal;
  }
}
```

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/k1zk3ses/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in this shape, one solution can be produced by using `Array.prototype.reduce()` as follows;

```js
var str = 'Group,Profession,Status,Count\n6,Fisherman,OfferAccepted,1\n6,Fisherman,All,1\n7,Fisherman,OfferAccepted,1\n7,Fisherman,All,1\n8,Banker,On Board,2\n8,Banker,All,2\n8,Cook,On Board,4\n8,Cook,All,4\n8,Developer,On Board,2\n8,Developer,All,2\n9,Banker,On Board,2\n9,Banker,OfferAccepted,1\n9,Banker,All,3',
   data = str.split("\n").map(s => s.split(",")).slice(1),
  jdata = data.reduce((p,c) => (p[c[1]] ? p[c[1]][c[0]] ? p[c[1]][c[0]][c[2]] = c[3]
                                                        : p[c[1]][c[0]] = {[c[2]]:c[3]}
                                        : p[c[1]] = {[c[0]]:{[c[2]]:c[3]}},p),{});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(jdata,null,2) + "</pre>");
```